# Detect if back button is pressed AND wait user action to pop to previous view

Tags: iphone, ios, button, uinavigationbar, back

I saw multiple questions about **how to detect when the user is pressing the "Back" button** on a UINavigationBar, but the answers does not solved my problem.

Indeed, I want to display a UIAlertView when user is pressing the UINavigationBar "Back" button, to ask him *"Do you want to save the changes ?"*.

I can display a UIAlertView when the user is pressing the "Back" button (with the following snippet), but the previous view is popped in the same time. And I don't want this behaviour ! I just want that the app **WAIT the user answer BEFORE** pop the previous view...

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Avertissement" message:@"Voulez-vous enregistrer les modifications effectuées ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Retour" otherButtonTitles:@"Oui", @"Non", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Thanks for you help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set action to the backButtonItem on the navigation bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207230/how-to-set-action-to-the-backbuttonitem-on-the-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Suggest you using you own `LeftbarButtonItem` instead of default Back-button event at `viewWillDisappear` like this:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  UIBarButtonItem *left=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionBack:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = left;
 [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)actionBack:(id)sender {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Avertissement" message:@"Voulez-vous enregistrer les modifications effectuées ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Retour" otherButtonTitles:@"Oui", @"Non", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

And use alert Delegate `clickedButtonAtIndex`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  
    {
        if(alertView.tag == 1)
        {
            // set your logic
        }
    }
```